# Error: The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the class 'Future<FirebaseUser> Function()'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

[I get this error while fetching the teacher id, what can be done??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez3jG.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using Future Function to get the current user, you can get the current user simply like this:

```
  User  teacher = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are trying to access a future result when it's not ready yet.

As you see, your `teacher` variable is a `Future<FirebaseUser>`, so at that point moving fast machine speed you reach the access to `teacher.uid` before it's completed and still a promise.

On that line that you call the teacher, change from:

```dart
Future<FirebaseUser> Function() teacher = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

To this:

```dart
FirebaseUser teacher = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
```

With this you code will wait until FirebaseAuth do all requests and return only the result.

You can look an example at https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/8a2f512e6d52fa8e47ffc53e55b2593de61e2085/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example/lib/profile.dart#L34
Also at https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage